# c++ virtual public inheritance init strange result?

Tags: c++

The output of the program below is:
5
5

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
public:
    int myInt;
    A(int n): myInt(n){}
    A(): myInt(5) {}
};


class B : virtual public A
{
public:
    B(int n):A(10) {}
    B():A(10) {}
};

class C : virtual public A
{
public:
    C(int n):A(3*n) {}
};

class D : public B, public C
{
public:
    D(int n=90) : C(2*n), B(n) {}
};

class E : public D
{
public:
    E(int n=20):D(n-1) {}
};

int main()
{
    D d(100);
    cout << d.myInt << endl;
    E e;
    cout << e.myInt << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Consider the object `d`. From what I understand the inheritance is constructed based on the order of the inheritance list (rather than the initialization list) so `B` class is constructed first with the param `100` which goes to class `A` with the parameter `10`. So now `A` sets `myInt` to the value `10`. The same goes for Class `c` and because `myInt` is virtual then it is set to the number `600`. I never expected `5`. why is this happening?

Comment: why don't you set a breakpoint in your constructors to A, start the program up in the debugger and find out what is going on?

Comment: @Thomas: debugging won't explain _why_ that happens though, only what happens.

Comment: I hope your production code doesn't use this anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See article in [parashift](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-inheritance-ctors.html):

> Because a virtual base class subobject occurs only once in an
>   instance, there are special rules to make sure the virtual base
>   class's constructor and destructor get called exactly once per
>   instance. The C++ rules say that virtual base classes are constructed
>   before all non-virtual base classes. The thing you as a programmer
>   need to know is this: constructors for virtual base classes anywhere
>   in your class's inheritance hierarchy are called by the "most derived"
>   class's constructor.